# Python3 pip install within virutalenv gives permission error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Created the following virtualenv

```
mkvirtualenv -p python3 cola-management-services
```

Run pip install

```
pip install pytz
```

And get the following error:

```
Collecting pytz
  Downloading https://devpi.dev.aws.company.com/root/pypi/+f/xxx/716540xxyyccabb/pytz-2017.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (511kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 512kB 7.6MB/s 
Installing collected packages: pytz
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jameslin/virtualenvs/cola-management-services/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Users/jameslin/virtualenvs/cola-management-services/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Users/jameslin/virtualenvs/cola-management-services/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/Users/jameslin/virtualenvs/cola-management-services/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/Users/jameslin/virtualenvs/cola-management-services/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/Users/jameslin/virtualenvs/cola-management-services/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/Users/jameslin/virtualenvs/cola-management-services/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 287, in clobber
    ensure_dir(dest)  # common for the 'include' path
  File "/Users/jameslin/virtualenvs/cola-management-services/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/Users/jameslin/virtualenvs/cola-management-services/bin/../lib/python3.6/os.py", line 210, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode, exist_ok)
  File "/Users/jameslin/virtualenvs/cola-management-services/bin/../lib/python3.6/os.py", line 210, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode, exist_ok)
  File "/Users/jameslin/virtualenvs/cola-management-services/bin/../lib/python3.6/os.py", line 220, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/lib'
```

First time seeing this problem... not sure what is wrong.

Tried with python2 and new virtualenv, same problem. I remember installing pytz on a different virtualevn and didn't get this problem.

Comment: `pytz` tries to install something in system-wide directory. You need `sudo pip install pytz`. But I am not sure will it broke virtualenv.

Comment: I did install pytz on another project and didn't have this problem

Comment: The `https://devpi.dev.aws.company.com/` URL bothers me; For me, `pip` downloads the `pytz` package straight from `https://pypi.python.org`. Makes me think you simply downloaded a bugged version from an (old? unsupported?) server.

Answer (score 0):

didn't use virtualenv in python3, but in python2, it didn't require sudo when use pip. guess you might need to use pip3

Comment: None of them require sudo.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm weird, the folder contains setup.cfg which has the following content

```
[install]
prefix=
```

If I remove that `setup.cfg` file, the pip install works fine...

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution I can think of is to run the CMD prompt As Administrator.

Comment: This is  on MacOS.